# How to approach this problem of utility?

Tags: utility

An individual has the following utility function: U(x, y) = 2xy + 3y, where x and y represent the quantities consumed of goods X and Y, respectively. The budget constraint is given by R = px + qy, with p being the price of good X and q being the price of good Y. Describe the general shape of the indifference curves associated with the utility function.

Let $ u_0 = y(2x+3) \iff \frac{u_0}{2x+3} = y $ but how do i determine the constant $ u_0 $

Comment: An indifference curve is defined by the equation $U(x,y)=u$ for some constant $u$. Write down that equation for your case and then think about what it looks like (you could solve the equation for $y$ and plot it or use calculus to find its slope and its curvature).

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are restricted to be nonnegative, then $u_0$ can be any nonnegative number. Each value of $u_0$ will give a different indifference curve. For $u_0=0$, the equation defines the line $y=0$. For $u_0>0$, the indifference curves all have the same basic shape: the positive branch of a hyperbola. If you know how to plot hyperbolas, then you should be able to plot the indifference curves. Try plotting for some different values of $u_0$.

Comment: @smcc so indifference curves are just infinite curves because from what you've said there exist an indifference curve for each $u_0$

Comment: There is an uncountably infinite number of indifference curves (one through every point where $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$). (Drawing all the indifference curves would amount to shading everything above the $x$-axis and to the right of the $y$-axis.)